# Storing Business Hours in a Database

Tags: database, database-design

I'm currently trying to work out the best way to store a business' hours of operation in a database.

For example:

Business A has the following hours of operation

- Monday: 9am - 5pm
- Tuesday: 9am - 5pm
- Wednesday: 9am - 5pm
- Thursday: 9am - 5pm
- Friday: 9am - 5pm
- Saturday: 9am - 12 Midday
- Sunday: Closed

Currently I'm have a data model similar to the following

```
CREATE TABLE "business_hours" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "day" varchar(16) NOT NULL,
    "open_time" time,
    "close_time" time
)
```

where the "day" is restricted to a choice of the 7 days of the week in code (through the ORM). To test if a business is closed on a certain day it checks if the open_time and close_time are NULL. It is related to the business through a intermediate table (Many To Many Relationship).

Does any one have any suggestions for this database scheme? Something about it doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: Why do you need an M-to-M relationship between the business_hours table and the businesses table? If you really going to make multiple businesses share the same record in business_hours, why? Semantically, the fact that "company C works from T1 to T2 on day D" is rather a value-object than an entity... The only good (?) reason I can imagine is storage size optimization (RDB version of Flyweight pattern, so to speak) if the number of businesses is expected to be huge...

Comment: What about lunch breaks? What about public holidays?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Overall, I see nothing wrong with this. Except...

1. I would store the day of week as an integer using whatever numbering system your native programming language uses (in its libraries). This will decrease the size of the database and remove string comparisons from your code.
2. I would probably put the foreign key to the business table right here in this table. That way you won't need a link table.

So I guess I would do:

```
CREATE TABLE "business_hours" (
     "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     "business_id" integer NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES "businesses",
     "day" integer NOT NULL,
     "open_time" time,
     "close_time" time
)
```

In my business logic, I would enforce a constraint that every "business" has **at least** 7 "business hours". (*At least* because Jon Skeet is right, you might want holiday hours.) Though you may want to relax this constraint by simply leaving off "business hours" for days that the business is closed.

Comment: How would you do 2? Having all entries for all businesses even when the day/times are the same?

Comment: I would say yes. Otherwise, consider what would happen if two businesses happen to share the same hours, but then one of them needs to change their hours. You would have to detect the fact that the hours are changed, and either create a new record, or edit the existing one, depending on whether its shared or not.

Comment: I absolutely would not share rows of this table between businesses. That kind of sharing just leads to pain. The business logic of the app should just enforce the constraint that every business has at least 7 "business_hours" references.

Comment: @Vinko: Remember that while the *values* are (currently) the same, the opening hours for two businesses are semantically distinct.

Comment: You could also use a bitmap of 7 bits for "day". That way you don't have to repeat the same entries Example all workdays have the same business hours, one entry is enough.

Comment: what about a restaurant with opening close more than one for each day..  e.g Monday 10am - 2pm and Monday 5 pm - 10 pm (it opens during lunch and dinner only) .  how your database schema will support this ?  how can we create such a flexible data structure in database?

Comment: @user384080 how about replacing `open_time` and `close_time` with `am_hours` and `pm_hours` on which its `am_hours` value will be a range like `10:00-14:00` and `pm_hours` will be `17:00-22:00` ?

Comment: Looking at http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification would be the best. They include a validFrom and validThrough date, which is very common for business or shops which have summer and winter opening hours

Answer (score 37):

One situation that isn't covered by this schema is several opening periods in a day. For example, the local pub is open 12:00-14:30 and 17:00-23:00.

Maybe a theatre box office is open for a matinee and an evening performance.

At that point you need to decide if you can have several entries for the same day, or if you need to represent different hours in the same row.

What about opening times that cross midnight. Say a bar is open 19:00-02:00. You couldn't just compare the opening and closing times with the time you want to test.

Answer (score 17):

I have learned that if you want to have google data markup recognize your data you should follow these guidelines:

https://schema.org/openingHours

http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification Contains "valid dates", which is very useful for some businesses.

https://schema.org/docs/search_results.html#q=hours

You should be fine without a primary key, unless you are allowing businesses to share the same hours with the join table - interestingly eventually you would have a finite amount of combinations; I'm not sure how many that would be :p

With one of my projects I used the columns:

> [uInt]business_id, [uTinyInt]day, [char(11)]timeRange

If you want to support OpeningHoursSpecification then you'll need to add validFrom and validThrough.

Time Range is formatted like:  hh:mm-hh:mm

Here's a function that parses it, 
you can also modify this function to parse just a single open/close, if you keep them as separate columns in the DB.

Out of my experience I would recommend that you allow multiple times within a day, allow for a way to tell if they are explicitly closed on that day, or opened 24 hours or 24/7.
I had mine say that if there was a day missing in the DB then the business was closed that day.

```
/**
 * parseTimeRange
 * parses a time range in the form of
 * '08:55-22:00'
 * @param $timeRange 'hh:mm-hh:mm' '08:55-22:00'
 * @return mixed ['hourStart'=>, 'minuteStart'=>, 'hourEnd'=>, 'minuteEnd'=>]
 */
function parseTimeRange($timeRange)
{
    // no validating just parsing
    preg_match('/(?P<hourStart>\d{1,2}):(?P<minuteStart>\d{2})-(?P<hourEnd>\d{1,2}):(?P<minuteEnd>\d{2})/', $timeRange, $matches);

    return $matches;
}
```

Answer (score 16):

It sort of depends on what you need to store it for and what the real-world data could look like.
If you need to be able to determine if the business is open at a certain point then it may be a bit awkward to query the scheme as laid out. More importantly, though, is: Would you ever need to cater for a mid-day closure?

Some options include;

- A scheme like what you have, but with the option to have multiple periods for the same day. It would cater for the lunch break, but would make it awkward to run a query that gives you the opening hours for a given day, say for presentation to a user.
- A bitmap style approach; "000000000111111110000000" for 9-5. The downside to this approach is that you have to choose a specific granularity, i.e. whole hours or half-hours or, indeed, minutes. The finer the granularity, the harder the data is to read for a human. You could use bitwise operators to store this value as a single number rather than a string of integers, but again it hurts legibility.

Answer (score 8):

Most of results works fine for the given scenario, but it wont be as effective if you have periods that runs through multiple days, eg. 8:00 AM ~ 2:00 AM, then I recommend using a multi period design.

```
    {
         id: 1,
         day: 1,
         periods: [
             0: { open: 08:00, close: 00:00 }
         ]
    },
    {
         id: 2,
         day: 2,
         periods: [
             0: { open: 08:00, close: 00:00 }
             1: { open: 00:00, close: 02:00 }
         ]
    }
```

**day**: number of day of the week
*if no periods, means it is closed*

Answer (score 0):

Might think about factoring in holidays by including additional fields for month of year/day of month/week of month.  Week of month has some minor subtlties "last" could for example be week 4 or 5 depending on the year.