# Opening hours in ice_cube

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ice-cube

How am I able to rule opening hours of a restaurant within single Schedule?

Mon-Fri 8-16 is quite easy:

```
schedule = Schedule.new(Time.parse(Date.yesterday.to_s + ' 8:00'), :duration => 60*60*8)
(...)
schedule.add_recurrence_rule Rule.daily.day(:wednesday)
schedule.add_recurrence_rule Rule.daily.day(:thursday)
(...)
schedule.occurring_at?(Time.now)
```

Problem is when trying to rule something like:
Mon 9-17,
Tu 16-01 (the next day after midnight)
etc.

Am I able to do this with that plugin?

Answer (score 3):

Just got email from an Ice_Cube author answering my question. Might be usefull:

> Unfortunately we strive to maintain backwards compatibility with the iCalendar standard - so you can't change durations on a per-rule basis.  If you want to accomplish something like the above, people either use multiple schedules, or store the durations separately (the latter is highly preferred)