# Is there a more efficient way to store a shop's hours?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, memory, memory-management

I have a model `Shop` and I want to store every `shop`'s opening and closing hours. If their hours were the same every day, it would be easy, just two attributes: `opening_time` and `closing_time`. But most businesses have different times on different days, plus holidays.

So as it stands, I would have to add two attributes for each weekday for a total of fourteen attributes, plus probably create an entirely new model `Holiday`, because it's unpredictable how many holidays any given business will take off.

It can be done, it just seems unnecessarily complicated for recording a businesses' hours, and I don't want to bloat my schema. Does anyone know of a better way?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but a similar question was discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1036603/5961578).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have 3 Models :

1. `Shop` - Business Entity
2. `Slot` - containing `start_time`, `end_time`, `weekly_exception` which belongs to `shop`

   Here, `weekly_exception` is an integer in `range(0..127)` which takes care for which weekday this slot is valid

   For Instance: `127 means (1111111) in base-2 representation => slot valid for all 7 weekdays`
3. `SlotException` - containing `blocked_start_time`, `blocked_end_time`, `exception_day`, `is_on_leave`  which belongs to shop

   Here, `exception_day` is date for which slot is blocked between `blocked_start_time` and `blocked_end_time` timings only.
    and `is_on_leave` is boolean take care for slot holiday.

Ruby code to get weekdays out of weekly_exception:

```
def get_weekdays(weekly_exception)
  i, count = 1, 0
  map, weekdays = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"], []
  while count < 7
    weekdays.push(map[count]) if (weekly_exception & i) > 0
    i = i << 1
    count += 1
  end
  return weekdays
end
```

Comment: That's really smart. How could you get Rails to interpret the weekly_exception range?

Comment: weekly_exception is just integer in database, we will process integer to get week_days etc. as per the need.